# Bootstraps table lines disappearing when used with popovers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I try to have a popover show up when I click on a table row, the popover shows but removes a line from the table.

I've tried adding a `div element` to the row and change the JQuery but to no avail.

```html
 
    <head>

   

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href = "test.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <div class="event-btn">
                    <div class = "btn-contents">
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div id = "s-cont">

              <table class = "table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope = "col"> Start </th>
                            <th scope = "col"> Session </th>
                            <th scope = "col"> Length </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr data-toggle ="popover" data-placement="top"  data-content = "HI" data-trigger = "click" >
                        <td> content 1 </td>
                        <td>content 2</td>
                        <td>content 3 </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-toggle ="popover" data-placement="top"  data-content = "HI" data-trigger = "click" >
                        <td> content 1 </td>
                        <td>content 2</td>
                        <td>content 3 </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-toggle ="popover" data-placement="top"  data-content = "HI" data-trigger = "click" >
                        <td>content 1 </td>
                        <td>content 2</td>
                        <td>content 3 </td>
                    </tr>
            </div>

            <script>
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({})
            </script>
    </body>
```

This works in CodePen and the lines in the tables are still removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have some styles on a parent element that interfere with a popover, you’ll want to specify a custom container so that the popover’s HTML appears within that element instead [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/). Use `data-container="body"` to fix the problem.

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({})
```

```html
<head>
 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href = "test.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <div class="event-btn">
                    <div class = "btn-contents"> </div>
            </div>

            <div id = "s-cont">

              <table class = "table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope = "col"> Start </th>
                            <th scope = "col"> Session </th>
                            <th scope = "col"> Length </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr data-toggle ="popover" data-placement="top"  data-container="body" data-content = "HI" data-trigger = "click" >
                        <td> content 1 </td>
                        <td>content 2</td>
                        <td>content 3 </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-toggle ="popover" data-placement="top"  data-container="body" data-content = "HI" data-trigger = "click" >
                        <td> content 1 </td>
                        <td>content 2</td>
                        <td>content 3 </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-toggle ="popover" data-placement="top"  data-container="body"  data-content = "HI" data-trigger = "click" >
                        <td>content 1 </td>
                        <td>content 2</td>
                        <td>content 3 </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
            </div>
  
    </body>
```

Comment: That's a fix! Thanks!